# Swap Objects in an array in C

Tags: c

I tried searching for this because I thought it must be on here but I couldn't figure it out.

Anyhow if I have an array of a struct in C such as:

```
struct structName array[];
```

and I wanted to swap the values of array[i] and array[i+1] how would I do it? I've seen elsewhere for int array[] but it doesn't seem to apply correctly because of pointers. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

The same way you'd swap anything:

```
struct structName tmp = array[i];
array[i] = array[i+1];
array[i+1] = tmp;
```

Comment: Okay, so I understand that. If I wanted to extract this into it's own method how would that work. Because I'm okay implementing that but running into issues when trying to extract it.

Comment: By putting the above code into a function.  If you are having specific issues, please edit your question to show your code, and to describe the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Copy structure #1 to a temporary structure variable;
2.Copy structure #1 to structure #2;
3.Copy the temporary structure variable into structure #2.
```

It is important to note that each member of the structure must be copied, one at a time. If there are nested structures within the structure, these must be copied in the same way. This makes the process much more involved, and much more tedious.

Comment: There is no need to copy each member individually.